# Moving Symfony Application Local Database to Web

Tags: symfony

I developed a application on my local system (Windows 7 & wamp)its working fine so I decided to deploy it to my shared hosting account

I create a blank database on server and then imported my local database file

but if try to login to my system I am getting table not found error although table are present in database

I am getting error like below

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'ezwebsto_ezwoms.WomsLog' doesn't exist") in
>   "AdminBundle:Default:home.html.twig

I suspect that the issue is because case sensitive table name, so renamed table name but still I am facing issue

can anyone guide me what is proper way to move local db of symfony application to web to p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL on Windows by default is NOT case sensitive. On Unix based system it is.
The best practice is to turn on case sensitive in MySQL settings, and in future moving database to server will be simple.

You have to set up variable

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

in your `my.ini` file. On Windows, default value is `1`.

But now, you have to map table name inside each entity, like wrote @prashant. Please compare table names with mapping names, and rename tables if necessary.

After change, your entity should look like:

```
/**
 * Content
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="content")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Content
{
    //some usefull code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to define the tablename in your entity class, with the Table annotation:

```
@ORM\Table(name="WomsLog")
```

As well make sure your table is correct in DB , W and L must be in upper case.